# variable inside controller not getting resolved to data resolved by promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

//inside a service   PService

```
this.getPTypes = function(){
        var types = PTypesFactory.get({});
        return types.$promise.then(function(result)
        {
            console.log(result.groups);
            return result.groups;
        });
    }
```

//inside a controller

```
$scope.groups = PService.getPTypes();
```

console log shows correct fetched REST data, but when I do

```
console.log($scope.groups);
```

I get

```
Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function}
```

which is promise API instead of the correct resolved data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you trying to use a asynchronous function like it was a synchronous one.

`then` is a method which returns a promise.

when invoking it with a callback that callback would not be invoked immediately, only when the response get back from the server.

#### You can write it like so:

**Service**

```
this.getPTypes = function(callback){
  PTypesFactory.get({}).then(callback);
}
```

**Controller**

```
PService.getPTypes(function(res){
  $scope.groups = res.data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Promises are used to handle asynchronous operations. The function you pass to the `then` method is called at some indeterminable point in time. You can't return a value from within it to some other point in execution.

Instead of calling `then` in your service, just return the promise:

```
this.getPTypes = function(){
    return PTypesFactory.get({}).$promise;
}
```

and handle its resolution in the controller:

```
$scope.groups = PService.getPTypes().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.groups);
});
```

Comment: moving the .then function to controller doesnt affect the output, its the same as mentioned in Question

Comment: @user494461 - Do you even need the `then`? Return `$promise` from the service and do `$scope.groups = PService.getPTypes();`.